# psiphon connects successfully but blocked sites are still blocked

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, vpn

I've installed psiphon and I launched it in vpn mode and it connected successfully. However, the sites I know are blocked in my country were still blocked.

This didn't use to happen, psiphon used to work great but now it seems like the device isn't tunneled at all.

Android version : 6.0.1
Psiphon client version is 164

Again it connects successfully but the effects I expect aren't there.

Comment: What version of Android were you using before, also are you using Psiphon built-in browser?

Comment: @xavier_fakerat hmm probably 4.0 IceCream, no I'm using tunnel mode,anyway it works now !!! I don't know how but it works